# How to add a week grouping column to data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that has columns similar to the two below (`df$date` and `df$day`). What I'd like to do is retrospectively add a `week` column that would essentially contain values such as `"Week 1"`, `"Week 2"`, `"Week 3"` etc. I'd like my ***week*** to run Monday to Sunday, so I'm wondering if there is a neat way to code this. A potential challenge is I don't have 7 entries for each week every time, such as in the example data below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = rev(c("09/09/2023", "07/09/2023", "05/09/2023", "02/09/2023",
           "31/08/2023", "29/08/2023", "28/03/2023")),
  day = rev(c("Saturday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Saturday", "Thursday",
          "Tuesday", "Monday"))
  )
```